# Best practice numpy roots

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization, polynomials

I am wondering what are the differences between these two ways of computing the roots of a polynom using numpy.

```
import numpy
polynom = [1,2,3,4]
print(sorted(numpy.roots(polynom)))
>>[(-1.6506291914393885+0j), (-0.17468540428030543-1.5468688872313967j), (-0.17468540428030543+1.5468688872313967j)]
```

and

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
polynom_reverse = [4,3,2,1]
polynom = Polynomial(polynom_reverse)
print(sorted(polynom.roots()))
>>[(-1.6506291914393871+0j), (-0.17468540428030613-1.5468688872313954j), (-0.17468540428030613+1.5468688872313954j)]
```

I am using Python 3.5 btw

Comment: (except the fact that the polynom order is reversed)

Comment: they both do, I will put the result they both output in the question!

Comment: you can try timing them using `timeit` because, i do not believe that the results themselves are going to be different. High order polynomials have no analytical solution so they both implement some numeric method, probably not the same one though. That might result in slight deviations between the roots computed but that would be on the 10th decimal place or so

Comment: timeit gives 85.4 µs and 132 µs respectively

Comment: If you already have a Polynomial object that you are working with then its method might be more convenient.  If you just need the roots and don't want to make a Polynomial then numpy.roots() would be a better choice.

Comment: one way or the other they are calculating the eigenvalues of the companion matrix. So it shouldn't be so different